# preg_match_all pattern creation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can i properly format regex pattern to find matches for strings contained between (* ''' and ''') from ex. something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, *'''Consectetur adipiscing elit'''. Quisque id diam sit amet
lectus semper blandit a sit amet nibh. *'''Phasellus fermentum nisi vitae lacus'''
scelerisque dapibus.
```

I have tried something like this:

```
preg_match_all("/\* \'\'\'(.+?)\'\'\'/i", $new_content, $matches);
```

But I get result like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
        0 => string '* '''Consectetur adipiscing elit''''
        1 => string '* '''Phasellus fermentum nisi vitae lacus''''
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
        0 => string 'Consectetur adipiscing elit'
        1 => string 'Phasellus fermentum nisi vitae lacus'
```

I don't work with regex almost at all, so i don't know exactly what am I doing!

Comment: +1 for your last sentence, and welcome here :-)

Comment: So, what is the problem? Everything is correct.

Comment: it looks to me like your regex is working already; you just need to read the values you want from `$matches[1]`.

Comment: `/(?<=\*''').*?(?=''')/`  Is the only improvement I can see.  But it's not really an improvement.  Just a different way of taking `$matches[1]`.  Maybe if you provided sample desired output?

Comment: @Serbas: Heh, just the obvious truth :-)

Comment: @M42: Yes, I know that it works, just thought that there is more "correct" way :-)

Comment: @Spudley: It is working, I was just confused with two arrays in results.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: Same as the previous reply, desired output is in the arrat $matches[1]

Comment: @wb_86 - the reason for two sets of results is that the first one is for the whole pattern, and the second one is for the part in the brackets. If you had any more sets of brackets in the pattern, you'd get additional sets of matches in the output array for those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
$str = <<<EOF
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, *'''Consectetur adipiscing elit'''. Quisque id diam sit amet
lectus semper blandit a sit amet nibh. *'''Phasellus fermentum nisi vitae lacus'''
scelerisque dapibus.
EOF;

$pattern = "~\*'''(.*?)'''~s";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(27) "Consectetur adipiscing elit"
  [1] =>
  string(36) "Phasellus fermentum nisi vitae lacus"
}
```

Explanation:

```
     ~      is the pattern delimiter
    \*      asterisk has to be escaped
   '''      ''' 
    ()      special matching group
   .*?      any char (except of the following ''', ? -> ungreedy)
   '''      '''
     ~      pattern delimter
     s      Option, includes newlines in .*
```

Comment: Thank you for replay and detaild explanation :-) I definitely need to study regex patterns for further use!

Comment: np.. You can start [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) to learn more. (but of course there are other resources as well)